# Add color to black and white in Gimp

Tags: colors, mask, gimp

In gimp I want to color in a black and white image, but without showing the black.  The process for photoshop is here http://penandoink.com/2012/09/26/adding-color-to-black-and-white-artwork-in-photoshop/

but I can't make it work in gimp.

How can I do this in gimp?

Edit - I worked it out. Follow the photoshop tutorial but past the mask to a white background, then invert your selection - which is crossed out in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Instant googling](http://www.tutorialgeek.net/2012/11/use-gimp-to-create-color-photos-from.html). Is this relevant for your needs ?